Uniqueness for the mild solution of a heat equation on the torus
Consider the following linear parabolic equation in one spatial dimension for $u=u(x,t)$ on the one-dimensional flat torus $\mathbb{T}^1,$ meaning $x \in \mathbb{T}^1$ and $t \in (0, T]:$
$$ \partial_t u- a \cdot\partial_{x}^2u +g(x,t)\cdot u= f(x,t),$$
with the constant $a > 0,$ and the given functions $g,f \geq 0,$ subjected to the strictly positive initial condition $u_0(x) \in C^1(\mathbb{T}^1).$
For $f$ and $g$ we have $f,g \in L^{\infty}((0, T), L^1(\mathbb{T}^1)).$
A mild solution $u \in C^0(\mathbb{T}^1 \times [0,T])$ (implicitly) satisfies
$$ u(x,t) = (G \ast u_0)(x,t) + \int_0^t \int_0^1 G(x-y,t-s)(f-g \cdot u)(y,s) \, dy ds,$$ where $G$ denotes the (one-dimensional) heat kernel on the torus.
I would like to show the uniqueness of such a mild solution. Let us a assume there a two different solutions $u_1$ and $u_2,$ hence the difference $w := u_1-u_2$ satisfies
$$ w(x,t) = -\int_0^t \int_0^1 G(x-y,t-s)\cdot (g \cdot w)(y,s) \, dy ds.$$
This implies that $w = 0,$ because $G$ and $g$ are both non-negative.
Is that reasoning correct/enough?
EDIT: Following the hint, I could proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
 \sup_{x}|w(x,t)| &\leq \sup_x \int_0^t \int_0^1 |G(x-y,t-s)|\cdot (|g| \cdot |w|)(y,s) \, dy ds \\
&\leq C \int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{t-s}} \int_0^1  g(y,s) \cdot |w|(y,s) \, dy ds \\
&\leq C \int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{t-s}} \int_0^1  g(y,s) \cdot \sup_y |w|(y,s) \, dy ds \\
&= C \int_0^t \frac{\sup_y |w|(y,s)}{\sqrt{t-s}} \, ds \int_0^1  g(y,s) \, dy \\
& \leq C \Vert g \Vert_{L^{\infty}((0, T), L^1(\mathbb{T}^1))} \int_0^t \frac{\sup_y |w|(y,s)}{\sqrt{t-s}} \, ds,
\end{align*} and by Gronwall's inequality I would obtain
$$ \sup_{x}|w(x,t)| \leq 0,$$ which implies $$ |w(x,t)| = 0.$$
Is that correct?

A hint: take a look at Gronwall's inequality (in its integral form). I would recommend to take a look at Chapter 4 of Cazenave-Haraux book

@rebo79 Thanks for the hint! What irritates me here is that I have two deal with two integrals instead of one as stated in Gronwall's inequality. How can I cope with that?
